# fatal error: RcppEigen.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, rcpp

I am very new to `Rcpp` and `RcppEigen` probably this is why i can not figute it out myself:

I just want to write a c++ function that includes the Eigen library. To test if it workes i took the following example from http://people.math.aau.dk/~sorenh/misc/Rdocs/Rcpp/RcppSHLIB.pdf:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppEigen.h>
RcppExport SEXP C_spdinv_eigen ( SEXP X_ ){
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
typedef Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> MapMatd;
const MapMatd X(Rcpp::as<MapMatd>(X_));
const MatrixXd Xinv(X.inverse());
return(Rcpp::wrap(Xinv));
}
```

But i get the following error:

```
rcpp-test.cpp:2:23: fatal error: RcppEigen.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rcpp-test.o] Error 1
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG    -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"    -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c rcpp-test.cpp -o rcpp-test.o 
Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("rcpp-test.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.
```

Compiling a script that only has the `#include <Rcpp.h>` is working perfectly.
The `RcppEigen.h`-file in located in the `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen/include` directory. I tried installing `RcppEigen` with `R CMD INSTALL ...` and `install.package`: neither worked.

My seccionInfo is

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C       
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=C        LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C      
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppEigen_0.3.2.1.1 Rcpp_0.11.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Matrix_1.1-1.1  grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-27 tools_3.0.2
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I fixed your capitalization a little.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not say **how** you attempted to compile your function. It matters:

- In a package, use `LinkingTo: RcppEigen`.
- In a function used with Rcpp Attributes, use a proper `Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)`.

There are numerous examples here, at the [Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org) and other places.  Follow them, but follow all steps.  Right now you have the compiler telling you that `RcppEigen` is unknown.

My [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book) details build issues  in Chapter 2.

Comment: Thank you very much Dirk. I Compiles it using the `Source`-Button in Rstudio. Including a line saying   `// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]` made it run. I did not know that i have to do this.

Comment: Where is the source for RccpEigen.h available for download. Hopefully for Fedora.

Comment: fifth hit in a google search: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppEigen/blob/master/inst/include/RcppEigen.h  (there is no "for Fedora" involved, this is just a .h file - no system dependencies).  But if you're trying to put the pieces together without installing the architecture (by following the voluminous Rcpp documentation) you're probably headed for trouble ...